# How to copy plain property from one POJO to nested property of another POJO?

Tags: java, json, solr

I have a pojo **PersonDocument**  which stores response from Solr. I am copying the contents of this class to  **Person** class using

```java
BeanUtils.copyProperties (persondoc,person);
```

But **address** variable is always mapped as null.
**pinCode** from  PersonDocument should be copied to **pinCode** in Address class. How to resolve this?

### Person.java

```java
    public class Person{
       private String name;
       private Address address;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

### Address.java

```java
    public class Address{
      private String streetName;
      private Long pinCode;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

### PersonDocument.java

```java
    
    public class PersonDocument{
      private String name;
      private Long pinCode;
    //getter and setter

    }
```

### PersonDocument JSON

```
{
"name" : "Mark",
"pincode" : "411017"
}
```

### **Expected Person JSON**

```
{
"name" : "Mark",
"address" : {
        "streetName" :  ,
        "pincode" : "411017"
    }
}
```

I have tried adding this in **PersonDocument**, still its not getting mapped:

```java
@JsonProperty("address.pinCode")
private Long pinCode;
```

Comment: if you could share your json structure it would be helpful

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti please see the expected json